# What are these dots either side of the variable?

Tags: php, string

I'm new to PHP / MySQL and I was just trying to get familiar with it all by following this tut:

http://www.allsyntax.com/tutorials/PHP/24/Building-a-Comments-Script/2.php

...here's an excerpt from the start of the script:

```
$inf = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE page = '".stripslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."' ORDER BY time ASC";
$info = mysql_query($inf);
f(!$info) die(mysql_error());
```

I understand what this is doing but I wanted to know why the

```
stripslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

has dots either side of it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Do not, I repeat, do not follow that tutorial. It teaches you some very bad practices. Just the piece of code you pasted above is a case of security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm just following it to get accustomed to PHP / MySQL - I'll look into writing more secure code at a later date.

Comment: It's not only security that's lacking. The author wants you to store date and time as text in MySQL. There are many questions here on StackOverflow from people who did that and are now suffering. There's also a matter of code style and in general the approach presented is far from a good one (let alone best)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The period is a [String Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).  Specifically, the concatenation operator.

In layman's terms, it glues strings together.

As you can see in the [`stripslashes`](http://de3.php.net/stripslashes) documentation, it is a function that returns a string.  So, the code is concatenating the first string `"SELECT ..."` with the result of the function, followed by the final string `" ORDER ..."`.

Comment: a concatenation operator to be precise

Comment: Okay thanks - I knew it was the concatenation operator but I didn't realise it was needed in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

The dot links the strings together.

Answer (score 2):

The dot (`.`) is the string concatenation operator in PHP.